# Nutch 1.13 index-links configuration

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

I am currently trying to extract the webgraph structure during my crawling run with Apache Nutch 1.13 and Solr 4.10.4.

According to the documentation, the index-links plugin adds `outlinks` and `inlinks` to the collection.

I have changed my collection in Solr accordingly (passed the respective fields in `schema.xml` and restarted Solr), as well as adapted the solr-mapping file, but to no avail.
The resulting error can be seen below.

```
bin/nutch index -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1 crawl/crawldb/ -linkdb crawl/linkdb/ crawl/segments/* -filter -normalize -deleteGone
Segment dir is complete: crawl/segments/20170503114357.
Indexer: starting at 2017-05-03 11:47:02
Indexer: deleting gone documents: true
Indexer: URL filtering: true
Indexer: URL normalizing: true
Active IndexWriters :
SOLRIndexWriter
    solr.server.url : URL of the SOLR instance
    solr.zookeeper.hosts : URL of the Zookeeper quorum
    solr.commit.size : buffer size when sending to SOLR (default 1000)
    solr.mapping.file : name of the mapping file for fields (default solrindex-mapping.xml)
    solr.auth : use authentication (default false)
    solr.auth.username : username for authentication
    solr.auth.password : password for authentication


Indexing 1/1 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexing 1/1 documents
Deleting 0 documents
Indexer: java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.index(IndexingJob.java:147)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.run(IndexingJob.java:230)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexingJob.main(IndexingJob.java:239)
```

Interestingly, my own research led me to the assumption that it is in fact non-trivial, since the resulting parse (without the plugin) looks like this:

```
bin/nutch indexchecker http://www.my-domain.com/
fetching: http://www.my-domain.com/
robots.txt whitelist not configured.
parsing: http://www.my-domain.com/
contentType: application/xhtml+xml
tstamp :    Wed May 03 11:40:57 CEST 2017
digest :    e549a51553a0fb3385926c76c52e0d79
host :  http://www.my-domain.com/
id :    http://www.my-domain.com/
title : Startseite
url :   http://www.my-domain.com/
content :   bla bla bla bla.
```

Yet, once I enable `index-links`, the output suddenly looks like this:

```
bin/nutch indexchecker http://www.my-domain.com/
fetching: http://www.my-domain.com/
robots.txt whitelist not configured.
parsing: http://www.my-domain.com/
contentType: application/xhtml+xml
tstamp :    Wed May 03 11:40:57 CEST 2017
outlinks :  http://www.my-domain.com/2-uncategorised/331-links-administratives
outlinks :  http://www.my-domain.com/2-uncategorised/332-links-extern
outlinks :  http://www.my-domain.com/impressum.html
id :    http://www.my-domain.com/
title : Startseite
url :   http://www.my-domain.com/
content :   bla bla bla
```

Obviously, this cannot fit into a single field, but I just want to have a single list with all the `outlinks` (I have read that the `inlinks` do not work, but I do not need them anyways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the fields in the `solrindex-mapping.xml` like this

```
<field dest="inlinks" source="inlinks"/>
<field dest="outlinks" source="outlinks"/>
```

Afterwards, make sure to *unload* and *reload* the collection, including a complete restart of Solr.

You did not specify how exactly you implemented the fields in `schema.xml`, but for me the following worked:

```
<!-- fields for index-links plugin -->
<field name="inlinks" type="url" stored="true" indexed="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="outlinks" type="url" stored="true" indexed="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Best regards and good luck!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the hint! I didn't think it was actually necessary to reload the collection... Stupid me, thanks for the hint!