# Solr Index missing fields

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, schema, nutch

I just found my Solr index is missing fields I need and thought I had specified. Looking into my Solr Admin Schema view, I see the respective fields flagged in the properties row but not in the schema row. For example this is a working field:

[image: content is working fine]

and this is a field I have in my schema.xml in Nutch and Solr but does not appear in the stored documents:

[image: outlinks is missing]

An excerpt from my schema file:

```
 <fields>
<field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" required="true"/>
<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

<!-- core fields -->
<field name="segment" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
<field name="digest" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
<field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

<!-- fields for index-basic plugin -->
<field name="host" type="url" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
<field name="url" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<!-- stored=true for highlighting, use term vectors  and positions for fast highlighting -->
<field name="content" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="title" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
<field name="tstamp" type="date" stored="true" indexed="false"/>


<!-- catch-all field -->
<field name="text" type="text_general" stored="false" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

<!-- fields for index-links -->
<field name="inlinks" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="outlinks" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

So what am I missing, why are outlinks not stored? What is the difference between the properties and the schema row? Is there some other place where I need to set the fields for storing?

EDIT:

The URL field type is defined as

```
 <fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
       <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: What is the definition of the field type `url`? My guess is that that is what `schema` refers to; `properties` refer to how the field is defined. Seeing as there is no doc count for the field, initial guess is that there never is anything submitted for the `outlinks` field.

Comment: Sounds sensible but the URL of the document itself is indexed correctly but not in- and outlinks. See edit for URL type specification.

Comment: Sure, but the `url` is a different field - there is nothing indicating that there is any value submitted at all for `inlinks` or `outlinks` - the count of documents containing a value seems to be zero.

Comment: Sure but why. I mentioned the url field, because it uses the same type so I would not see the url type definition as the culprit. It seems like there are never any links submitted or stored but why. I have 70 Million links in my crawldb.

Comment: Have you actually defined your inlinks/outlinks in the solr-mapping? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757606/nutch-1-13-index-links-configuration

Comment: Thanks that was the missing piece!